# Angular add and remove classes triggered by method without jquery

Tags: angular, typescript, angular10

I have some code which I want to use with animate.css to add and remove a class in a div.

Here is the code:

app.component.html

```
<button (click)="toggleMethod()">Toggle Classes</button>

<div class="myDiv">
    // Stuff here
</div>

app.component.ts

toggle = false;


toggleMethod() {
    
    if (this.toggle === true) {
        //Do this without JQ $('.myDiv').removeClass('animate__animated animate__fadeInLeft');
    } else if (this.toggle === false) {
      //Do this without JQ $('.myDiv').addClass('animate__animated animate__fadeInLeft');
    }
    this.toggle = !this.toggle; 
  
}
```

How can I do the above without using jQuery (the Angular way) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Angular instead of angularjs, try:

app.component.html

```
<button (click)="toggleMethod()">Toggle Classes</button>  
<div class="myDiv" [class]="{'animate__animated': toggle, 'animate__fadeInLeft': toggle}">
    // Stuff here
</div>
```

app.component.ts

```
toggle: boolean = false;

toggleMethod() {
    this.toggle = !this.toggle;      
}
```